# Laravel Sail Publish Image to DockerHub

Tags: laravel, docker

can anyone please tell me how I can publish and successfully run an image to DockerHub from a Laravel Sail project?

Essentially I ran `sail artisan sail:publish` and inside docker/8.0 I created an upload_image.sh script that builds and then pushes my image to DockerHub. What I want to know is how do I run my image now?

I'm running `docker run -it -p 8000:80 -v $PWD/html:/var/www/html <DOCKER_USERNAME>/<IMAGE NAME>` and it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6tyc.jpg)

Any help would be brilliant.

TIA

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, same error .. have you found any solution yet??